# Family of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was solving a question that said that I have to prove that the intersection of arbitrary family of rings is a ring. I have looked through the chapter and I have googled it but I cannot find a definition. I am assuming it means that two rings that have something in common because as I understand if the intersection is empty then it cannot be a ring. If anyone has any feedback that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean intersection of arbitrary family of *subrings* of a given ring $R$? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023637/proving-that-the-intersection-of-two-subrings-of-r-is-also-a-subring-of-r

Comment: @M.Nestor yes it definitely says arbitrary family of rings.

Comment: In that case, the claim is false, because as you noted in your post, the rings may not intersect.